# LaTeX health check

Tags: beamer, installing, beamerarticle

Is there any health check facility for testing the installation?

When compiling

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
    Hello
\end{document}
```

I receive in the log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.4.30)  25 MAY 2015 08:22
entering extended mode
.....
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasearticle.sty
Package: beamerbasearticle 2012/04/15  (rcs-revision cc6557182d97)

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
```

On sharelatex, I receive also error messages, the 1st one being

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasearticle.sty, line 61
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.61 \fi

The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [override]
Adding the global options:
  ,override
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

Comment: The `beamerarticle` package is not meant to be used along with the `beamer` class. The error is the same, as far as I can see; but you're comparing the console output with the log file, the latter containing more information, because ShareLaTeX runs TeX in non interactive mode.

Comment: @egreg Hmm, you are right, thank you. Due to some misunderstanding, or carelessness, I used this construction in my macro in the 2010 version of LaTeX, with no problem, for years.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because explained in comments